# POST request of Node rest API not working suddenly

Tags: node.js, rest

My node rest API stopped working suddenly when I try to send POST request. It, again and again, shows **"cannot read property 0 of undefined"** in postman console. I am using amazon s3 for my image storage. Here is my code for creating product in controller:

```
  exports.cars_create = (req, res, next) => {

  let imagebody = req.body;

  imagebody.carImage = req.files[0].location;

  imagebody._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

  const car = new Car(imagebody);
  car
      .save()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result, "Car");
        res.status(200).json(result);

    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
  };
```

And here is my multer middleware:

```
exports.multerFunction = (direct) => {

aws.config.update({
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  secretAccessKey:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  region: 'us-east-1'
})

var s3 = new aws.S3()

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    acl: 'public-read',
    bucket: 'onexxxxxxxxx',
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now()+file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-'));
    }
  })
})

return upload

}
```

Router code:

```
router.post("/", uploadMW.multerFunction('/cars').any('carImage'), CarsController.cars_create);
```

This all has been working till last day properly, now I am not able to identify what wrong happened with the POST request.

Comment: Please verify are you sending image in the files param.

Comment: Yes I am sending image as file. Still getting error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're not getting the image. Make sure you're sending the image, the key name for that image is correct as well as data which is coming from the front end is form data.

Comment: Yes I am sending an image with proper name but still getting error

Comment: can you make sure that the front end is sending data as form data?

Comment: The error is coming because it's not able to execute this line `  imagebody.carImage = req.files[0].location;` as req.files is empty.

Comment: Ohk I got that so can you provide a viable solution for this? As this req.body was working before properly

Comment: It Worked. I don't know the reason behind this, but, initially, I was sending POST request on chrome's extension of the postman. I downloaded the proper system version of it and the same code worked now.

Comment: Maybe. Thanks for your time